# How to implement the bilateral filter through tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to implement the Gaussian and Bilateral filter through Tensorflow. As for Gaussian, I'm done but have little clues for the Bilateral, any suggestions will be appreciated. Here is my Gaussian code.

```
def Gaussian_kernel(nsig= 2):
    filter_size = 13
    interval = (2*nsig+1.)/(filter_size)
    ll = np.linspace(-nsig-interval/2., nsig+interval/2., filter_size+1)
    kern1d = np.diff(st.norm.cdf(ll))
    kernel_raw = np.sqrt(np.outer(kern1d, kern1d))
    kernel = kernel_raw/kernel_raw.sum()
    kernel = kernel.astype(np.float32)
    weights_g = np.zeros((filter_size, filter_size, 1, 1))
    weights_g[:, :, 0, 0] = kernel
    weights_g = weights_g.astype(np.float32)

return weights_g

weight_g = Gaussian_kernel(20)
x_gaussian = tf.nn.conv2d(x, weights_g, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a 2D Gaussian Filter in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52012657/how-to-make-a-2d-gaussian-filter-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Actually, it's also the Gaussian Filter, and I'm stuck with the Bilateral filter, thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to do it  ?